# PowerShell Unable to find type

Tags: powershell

I'm having trouble with an error when I try to run my PowerShell script from the command line:

```
Unable to find type [System.Windows.Forms.ListViewItem]
```

I have tried different ways to import the required classes:

```
using assembly System.Windows.Forms
using namespace System.Windows.Forms
using namespace System.Drawing
```

```
Add-Type System.Windows.Forms
```

In PowerShell ISE, I can run my script without any errors. But when I try to execute my script from CMD it doesn't work. It's exactly the same code and the same script files. This is the command I use to execute the script in CMD followed by the error messages:

```
C:\Users\Admin>powershell -File "C:\Folder\Main.ps1"
```

```
At C:\Folder\Main.ps1:35 char:30
+ ...            return (([int](([System.Windows.Forms.ListViewItem]$a).Sub ...
+                                 ~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~
Unable to find type [System.Windows.Forms.ListViewItem].
At C:\Folder\Main.ps1:35 char:114
+ ... umnIndex].Text)) - ([int](([System.Windows.Forms.ListViewItem]$b).Sub ...
+                                 ~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~
Unable to find type [System.Windows.Forms.ListViewItem].
At C:\Folder\Main.ps1:37 char:41
+ ... return ([String]::Compare(([System.Windows.Forms.ListViewItem]$a).Sub ...
+                                 ~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~
Unable to find type [System.Windows.Forms.ListViewItem].
At C:\Folder\Main.ps1:37 char:115
+ ... [$this.columnIndex].Text, ([System.Windows.Forms.ListViewItem]$b).Sub ...
+                                 ~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~
Unable to find type [System.Windows.Forms.ListViewItem].
    + CategoryInfo          : ParserError: (:) [], ParentContainsErrorRecordException
    + FullyQualifiedErrorId : TypeNotFound
```

The error messages refer to the code below. This is my only class in that script:

```bash
class ListViewItemComparer : System.Collections.IComparer {
    [int]$sortOrder
    [String]$columnType
    [int]$columnIndex

    ListViewItemComparer() {
        $this.sortOrder = 1
        $this.columnType = "String"
        $this.columnIndex = 0
    }
    ListViewItemComparer([int]$sortOrder, [String]$columnType, [int]$columnIndex) {
        $this.sortOrder = $sortOrder
        $this.columnType = $columnType
        $this.columnIndex = $columnIndex
    }

    [void] ChangeSorting([int]$columnIndex, [String]$columnType) {
        if($this.columnIndex -eq $columnIndex) {
            $this.sortOrder *= -1
        } else {
            $this.columnIndex = $columnIndex
            $this.sortOrder = 1
        }
        $this.columnType = $columnType
    }

    [int] Compare([Object]$a, [Object]$b) {
        if($this.columnType -eq "Number") {
            return (([int](([System.Windows.Forms.ListViewItem]$a).SubItems[$this.columnIndex].Text)) - ([int](([System.Windows.Forms.ListViewItem]$b).SubItems[$this.columnIndex].Text))) * $this.sortOrder
        } else {
            return ([String]::Compare(([System.Windows.Forms.ListViewItem]$a).SubItems[$this.columnIndex].Text, ([System.Windows.Forms.ListViewItem]$b).SubItems[$this.columnIndex].Text)) * $this.sortOrder
        }
    }
}
```

I'm using the type `System.Windows.Forms.ListViewItem` at other places too in my code, but there is no problem outside of a class. I don't even have to write the whole class path, just ``ListViewItem` works as well.

Can somebody tell me why the type `System.Windows.Forms.ListViewItem` is not recognized?
Why is it recognized outside the `ListViewItemComparer` class in the same script file?
Why does this error occur when I run the script from CMD and not in PowerShell ISE?

Comment: Call `Add-Type -AssemblyName System.Windows.Forms` in `main.ps1`, then move the class definitions to a separate file and dot-source it from `main.ps1`

Comment: Wow, thank you, it works with zero errors! But what's the reason? When I use `Add-Type -AssemblyName System.Windows.Forms` and keep the class in the same file, it doesn't work. When I put the class into another file and add it back to the same scope, it works. Why? What's the difference?

Comment: Because of timing - PowerShell tries to parse and emit types for all `class` definitions in a script _before_ it starts executing - it works in PowerShell ISE because the ISE binary already has a dependency on System.Windows.Forms, so the assembly is already loaded

Comment: That's interesting. But isn't that really stupid from PowerShell? How are you supposed to use types when it's impossible to load them before using them? Except for this work around

Comment: The reason it's made that way is that (one of) the original use cases for custom `class/enum` definitions was as data contracts for parameters - define `enum MyOptions { A, B, C}`, apply type constraint `[MyOptions]` to a parameter, and all of a sudden the caller gets argument completion for free - but that requires the types to be compiled and emitted _before_ the script actually runs (because parameter binding has to take place _ahead of_ execution). The original vision was never to replicate the full scope of type definitions features from C# for example

Comment: I see, that makes sense. Just got to know it so you don't run into that problem :) Thanks for the explanation

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Class definitions will be parsed prior to any execution of your script. You can wrap your class with an Invoke-Expression command like so:

```
add-type -AssemblyName System.Windows.Forms
iex @'
  class ListViewItemComparer : Collections.IComparer
    {
    ....
    }
'@
```

This will defer compilation until the required assembly is loaded.

Note that errors in your class will now be reported relative to the beginning of the `iex` string. If you want the class to report proper file/line info then it's better to put it into a separate file like so:

```
add-type -AssemblyName System.Windows.Forms
. .\ListViewItemComparer.ps1
```

It depends on how you want to go about logging and error reporting.